# Preloader with progress (0 to 100) showing pageload in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, frontend, loader

https://thieb.co/
check this url their is a loader which shows pageload progress 0 to 99, couldn,t recreate it

I tried addeventlistener document.readystate xmlhttprequest but nothing work as excepted or i couldn't implement it correctly, i implemented load and progress state in listener but it runs only once useeffect even without dependency array . any idea how to implement it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Loader = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleLoad = () => {
      setProgress(100);
    };

    const handleProgress = (event) => {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        const loadedPercentage = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        setProgress(Math.round(loadedPercentage));
      }
    };

    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener("load", handleLoad);
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
    xhr.open("GET", window.location.href);
    xhr.send();

    return () => {
      xhr.removeEventListener("load", handleLoad);
      xhr.removeEventListener("progress", handleProgress);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Loading...</h1>
      <div>{`${progress}%`}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Loader;
```

i want the loader like this https://thieb.co/
which shows progress of pageload